# Space+Tab triggers AltTab and outputs Space

Tags: autohotkey, alt-tab

This Autohotkey script works great as a remap for Alt+Tab. However, I've noticed that it also still outputs a `Space` the moment `Tab` is pressed down (with `Space` still held down). This typically is not a problem except when moving out of applications in which `Space` has a function, e.g. it will pause music in Spotify. How can I avoid that?

```
~Space & Tab::AltTab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tilde prefix (~)](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) prevents AHK from blocking the Space key-down/up events. It allows the key event to pass through.

If you remove ~, Space [loses its original function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo). To avoid this, make the Space key to send itself:

```
Space & Tab::AltTab

Space::Send {Space}
```